# SwiftUI - zIndex change not working for item inside of LazyVStack

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, pinchzoom, lazyvstack

I have problem with *zIndex* in my app with collection of images
I've added pinch zoom to the image, but when image is zoomed it does not get on top of other images which are next in the collection.

When using VStack then everything is fine. Problem only when using LazyVStack

Here is source code of content view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: PostsViewModel
    
    init(_ viewModel: PostsViewModel? = nil) {
        let vm = viewModel != nil ? viewModel : PostsViewModel()
        
        _vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: vm!)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if vm.isLoading {
            ProgressView()
        } else {
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack (spacing: 34) {
                    ForEach(vm.collectionResponse.data, id: \.id, content: {
                        post in
                        PostView(imageUrl: post.attachments.first!.url)
                    })
                }
                .padding([.horizontal], 12)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PostView SourceCode:

```
struct PostView: View {
    @State var imageUrl: String
    @State var offset: CGPoint = .zero
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 0
    @State var scalePosition: CGPoint  = .zero
    
    init(imageUrl: String) {
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }
    var body: some View {
        KFImage(URL(string: imageUrl))
            .cacheMemoryOnly()
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(maxWidth: getRect().width, maxHeight: 500)
            .cornerRadius(12.0)
            .offset(x: offset.x, y: offset.y)
            .overlay(
                ZoomGesture(
                    scale: $scale,
                    offset: $offset,
                    scalePosition: $scalePosition)
            )
            .scaleEffect(
                1 + (scale < 0 ? 0 : scale),
                anchor: .init(x: scalePosition.x, y: scalePosition.y))
            .zIndex(scale > 0 ? 1000 : 0)
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You could try applying a `zIndex` to one of the parent containers, starting with the `LazyVStack`.

Comment: I've already tried to put zIndex pretty much everywhere I could, but no luck